# how to get seconds, minutes, and hours in a proper form?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, reusability

I managed to create this code that sets the timer for the songs....... the problem is, as you can see, that I have to repeat the same line of code for two different functions ("tiempo" and "duracion") where the only difference is that in one I want to know the .duration time and in the other the .currentTime.

So I want to isolate the part of code that repeats and call it later but I don't know how to do it.

The variable "totalNumberOfSeconds" needs to change its content in both functions, and if I isolate the code that repeats the "result" is NaN.

"audio" is the variable that contains the tag `<audio>` from html with the songs and "timer" is a `<span>` tag that contains "0:00/0:00" for the time counter.

**
**

```
audio.ontimeupdate = function() {totalTiempo()};

function totalTiempo() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = tiempo() + '/' + duracion()
}


function tiempo() {
     totalNumberOfSeconds = Math.floor(audio.currentTime)
     const hours = parseInt( totalNumberOfSeconds / 3600 );
     const minutes = parseInt( (totalNumberOfSeconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60 );
     const seconds = Math.floor((totalNumberOfSeconds - ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60))));
     const result = (minutes < 10 ?  + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
     console.log(result)
     return result
}

function duracion() {
     totalNumberOfSeconds = Math.floor(audio.duration)
     const hours = parseInt( totalNumberOfSeconds / 3600 );
     const minutes = parseInt( (totalNumberOfSeconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60 );
     const seconds = Math.floor((totalNumberOfSeconds - ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60))));
     const result = (minutes < 10 ?  + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
     console.log(result)
     return result
}
```

Comment: you have a typo on the result line where you left off the "0" pad for minutes. also I'm not sure if parseInt does the same thing as Math.floor, but Math.floor is definitely the right thing you want for hours and minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by making a function that takes a parameter, like so:

```js
function convertTimeToString(time) {
     totalNumberOfSeconds = Math.floor(time)
     const hours = parseInt( totalNumberOfSeconds / 3600 );
     const minutes = parseInt( (totalNumberOfSeconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60 );
     const seconds = Math.floor((totalNumberOfSeconds - ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60))));
     const result = (minutes < 10 ?  + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
     console.log(result)
     return result
}
```

You can then call this function later using whatever variable you want, like this:

```js
function tiempo() {
     return convertTimeToString(audio.currentTime)
}

function duracion() {
     return convertTimeToString(audio.duration)
}
```

You can also call it directly within the `getTotalTiempo` function like this:

```js
function totalTiempo() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = convertTimeToString(audio.currentTime) + '/' + convertTimeToString(audio.duration)
}
```

Comment: thanks bro...... i've started learning js a few weeks ago and i didn't understood quite well the parameters thing, so aside the coding problem itself this helped me a lot in that too!

Answer (score 0):

```js
 
function totalTiempo() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = tiempo(audio.currentTime) + '/' + duracion(audio.duration)
}
    function getTime(time) {
         totalNumberOfSeconds = Math.floor(time)
         const hours = parseInt( totalNumberOfSeconds / 3600 );
         const minutes = parseInt( (totalNumberOfSeconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60 );
         const seconds = Math.floor((totalNumberOfSeconds - ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60))));
         const result = (minutes < 10 ?  + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
         console.log(result)
         return result
    }
```